# Can anyone explain the difference between fftw_plan_dft_2d and fftw_plan_dft_1d?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, fftw

whats the difference between the both?
I have an Image matrix and I have flattened that into a fftw_complex continuous array?
which one shall I go for fftw_plan_dft_2d or fftw_plan_dft_1d?

I tried both but the behavior of both are quite different?

I tried to read the documentation but couldn't get much with respect to their differences and their usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your question is really about Fourier Transforms in general.  Specifically what is the difference in a 1-Dimensional FFT and a 2-Dimensional FFT.

The short answer is that a 2D FFT is the same as the following:

1. Apply a 1-D FFT independently to each row in the matrix.
2. Take the result from step 1 and apply a 1-D FFT independently to each column in the matrix.

Both fftw plans take in flattened complex matrix, however, the fftw_plan_dft_2d uses the n0 and n1 size parameters to correctly be able to interpret your complex array as a 2D matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The 1D dft Y of a signal X of size n writes:

[image]

The [2D dft is defined as](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002ddimensional-Transforms.html#Multi_002ddimensional-Transforms)

> the separable product of the given 1d transform along each dimension of the array.

Hence, the 2D dft consists in taking the dft over the first dimension, and then taking the dft on the other direction. It writes:

[image]

Notice that taking the dft over the other dimension first does not change the outcome :

[image]

Indeed, the sums can be [factored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_transform), see also [the doc of opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html):

[image]

It's different from a 1D dft over the whole flattened array, which does not feature this property. 2D Linear image filters based on convolution to a kernel (gaussian or whatever) rely on the 2D dft to turn the convolution into a pointwise multiplication in the Fourier space. If the image is 2D, the transformed image is also 2D. See this [course](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~emmanuel/courses/cs545/S14/slides/lecture10.pdf) for illustration.